# Use file_get_contents() and implode() to pass array to javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a simple image gallery which shows images and related caption. 
All images are inside a directory and caption in another (as single files). A php script lists all files in both directories and pass arrays to a javascript wich change image and caption when the user press a button.

```
            [...]    
            for($x = 2; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
                $filesi[$x] = $imgdirectory."/".$lsi[$x];
            }

            for($x = 2; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
                $filename = $capdirectory."/".$lsc[$x];
                $filesc[$x] = file_get_contents($filename);
            }

            //Create array for JS
            $captions =  '["' . implode('", "', $filesc). '"]';
            $images =  '["' . implode('", "', $filesi). '"]';
?>    
<script>
            var captions = <?php echo $captions; ?>;
            var images = <?php echo $images; ?>;
            [...]
```

Images work properly and I can also print caption's file name instead of caption
i.e.

```
$filesc[$x] = $filename;
```

but when I use "file_get_contents()" to read file the gallery stops working.

If I echo $captions and manually set $captions with the very same output 
e.g.

```
$captions='["first caption","second caption", "..."]';
```

the gallery works properly, so the array should be properly formatted...

Thank you in advance

SOLUTION
I was creating an array with two empty elements (0,1) in order to avoid ./ and ../ in file list, so I have added a +2 to the lsi index.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $lenght-2; $x++) {
                $filesi[$x] = $imgdirectory."/".$lsi[$x+2];
            }
```

In addition I have used json_encode, as suggested, instead of manual json encodig. The output seems to be the same but now the gallery works!

```
var images = <?php echo json_encode($filesi); ?>;
```

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand use json_encode function instead.

Comment: I have the same problem using `<?php echo json_encode($filesc) ?>;`  in addition several _undefined_ are introduced both in pictures and captions

Comment: Thank you for the advice, using json_encode gallery works properly. The _undefined_ bug is related to an index issue explained above.

Answer (score 0):

In JS you have to escape new lines in strings like this:

```
var multilineString = "this is\
just an example";
```

Maybe try to use trim() and str_replace() if you don't want to make it easier with json_encode().

UPDATE

Then I was wrong. Did you know that you can push items to arrays with just `$array[] = 'item';`?

Comment: I am quite a newbie in PHP and JS, maybe the problem was bounded to escaping. Thank you for the info about pushing item in arrays :)